# Form not posting when using unobtrusive validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I've been trying to get this problem fixed for several hours now, but can't seem to find out what's wrong here.

I have a view with a few fields that I want to post to my controller. Now, I want to check for validation errors on the client side. I've used this in several projects before by adding:
- jquery.js (version 1.12.1)
- jquery.validate.js (version 1.14.0)
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js (version 3.2.3)
- jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js (version 3.2.3)

As soon as a I reference jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js, the client sided validation works. But when I press the submit button, it just won't submit the form anymore. It just won't hit the controller.

My view is as following:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="portlet light bordered">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
                <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase font-dark">Auto toevoegen</span>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                @Html.ActionLink("Terug", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-circle green btn-outline btn-sm" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Car", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Merk, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Merk, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Merk)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kenteken, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Kenteken, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kenteken)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kilometervergoeding, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Kilometervergoeding, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kilometervergoeding)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DefaultCar, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DefaultCar)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefaultCar)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" class="btn blue" />
                            @Html.ActionLink("Annuleren", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-white" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller action looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [DisableValidation]
    public ActionResult Create(CarViewModel model)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        try
        {
            var tblCar = mapper.Map<CarViewModel, tblCar>(model);

            _carAppService.Insert(tblCar);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Add proper error messages
            Logger.Debug("Error occured during car adding process: " + ex.InnerException);

            //add common container with errors
            TempData["Error"] = "Er is iets fout gegaan :(";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

The scripts are loading in a bundle on startup and are loading in the order stated above. Now as soon as I remove the jquery.validate.unobtrusive from my bundle config, the submit button works. The client sided validation doesn't work anymore then though.

Does any know what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Any javascript specifically for the submit button that we should know about? If it's not hitting the controller, it sounds like the validation is preventing the submit for sure.

Comment: Nope! There is no javascript behind the button. And yeah, it looks like the validation prevents the submit to the controller. But I don't see get any messages or errors in the console.

Comment: Looking through at my projects, we seem to always include them in this order: `jquery-{version}.js`, `jquery.unobtrusive*`, `jquery.validate*`. Also, 1.12.1 seems very outdated for jquery, particularly since your jquery.validate is a higher version - could be an incompatibility issue. Finally, are you using the default `jqueryval` bundle? Because it's not rendered by default on the `_Layout` view, and needs to be manually referenced on your view: `@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}`

Comment: Hmm, I updated my jquery to 2.2.4, couldn't load unobtrusive before validate though. It gives a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined" error if I do that.

By the way, I am using the asp.net boilerplate Zero template. It loads the scripts in the following order:
1. JQuery
2. JQuery_Validation
3. JQuery_Unobtrusive
4. Jquery_Unobtrusive_Ajax

Comment: Interesting. Nonetheless, are you sure that the scripts are being loaded properly? Perhaps use Chrome Dev tools, or similar, to verify that they are loading, and then see if maybe there is any network activity when you click the submit button (wrong url perhaps?). Also worth checking is if the text colour of the error messages is the same as the background, and so you're just not seeing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I fixed the problem!

This answer will most likely only be useful is you make use of ASP.NET Boilerplate Zero template.

In ~/Common/Scripts a Javascript file was added (jquery-validation-custom.js).

The content messed with the submit button. I replaced it with my own version of a custom validation handler for modals and now it works!